# Eliminating white lines before the start of text

Tags: python, string

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but I could not find what I was looking for.

I am trying to eliminate the white lines before any text in a string. For example if I have this string:

```
 fdhsfhsadf
fsdhfsadjf

fhsdjf
```

I want to convert it to this string:

```
 fdhsfhsadf
fsdhfsadjf

fhsdjf
```

I have a regular expression that works in the examples that I have, but I want to know if this will work in all cases or if there is a better way to do it.

```
re.sub(r"^\s*$",r"",text,count=1)
```

My idea of why this works is because this implementation of sub first tries to adjoin as much text as possible, and then substitute it. But maybe there is an implementation of sub that does not do that and my code is useless there.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the string [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) method.

```
s = """


 fdhsfhsadf
fsdhfsadjf

fhsdjf
"""

print(s.lstrip('\n'))
```

will print

```
 fdhsfhsadf
fsdhfsadjf

fhsdjf
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand your solution. Do you think that my solution is wrong?

Comment: I've not tested your method but since you asked "or if there is a better way to do it." I think the answer is yes. Imo one should only reach for the `re` module when you can't achieve what you are trying to do with pythons built in string methods.